# Getting data from a specific port

Tags: java, methods, serial-port

This is the method and I want to get the variable data from this method to use it in another one.

```
    public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        try {
            int available = input.available();
            byte chunk[] = new byte[available];
            input.read(chunk, 0, available);

            // Displayed results are codepage dependent

            data =new String(chunk);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please formulate your question properly.Whats the issue you are facing ? Is this a problem of data to be read by other Threads / methods?

Comment: this method read adata that i want to use in another class to do authentication and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depend on what you are trying to achieve, the simplest way is to call the other method (say its name `processData` ) directly from `serialEvent` and pass to it the data you received from the `COM` port e.g. `processData(new String(chunk));`

The problem with this approach is that if your method `processData` doing something heavy it will block the `serialEvent`.

Alternative approach is to have a separate `thread` to process that data, which you can communicate to an implementation of `concurrent.BlockingQueue`. So inside `serialEvent` you just push the data to the queue and continue without waiting for `processData` to finish.

Just search for Producer/Consumer pattern with BlockingQueue and you will find plenty of code examples.